# Set first party cookie in PHP

Tags: php

How can we set a first party and third party cookie in php

Comment: *smiles* I don't think you will have much luck there... (Hint: Third Party Cookie)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set a cookie using `setcookie()`

However, I don't believe you actually know the difference between 1st and 3rd party cookies.

Whenever you browse to a website, that page can set a cookie. That is called a 1st party cookie. You browsed directly to the page, and now that page gives you a cookie.

However, if the page had some Javascript that pulled in a script from another website, and it tried to set a cookie, the browser would see it as a 3rd part cookie. This is a feature used often by Analytics and Ads that want to track users.

3rd party cookies and 1st party cookies can be disabled individually to protect the user.